# Using pycrypto, how to import a RSA public key and use it to encrypt a string?

Tags: python, rsa, pycrypto

The RSA public key:

pubkey = 'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBA3UAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC35eMaYoJXEoJt5HxarHkzDBEMU3qIWE0HSQ77CwP/8UbX07W2XKwngUyY4k6Hl2M/n9TOZMZsiBzer/fqV+QNPN1m9M94eUm2gQgwkoRj5battRCaNJK/23GGpCsTQatJN8PZBhJBb2Vlsvw5lFrSdMT1R7vaz+2EeNR/FitFXwIDAQAB'

how to import it and use it to encrypt a string?

I tried the following code but RSA.construct() raises exception (TypeError: must be long, not str).

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Util import asn1
from base64 import b64decode

keyDER = b64decode(pubkey)
seq = asn1.DerSequence()
seq.decode(keyDER)
keyPub = RSA.construct((seq[0], seq[1]))
print keyPub.encrypt('mysecret', 32)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5
from base64 import b64decode,b64encode

pubkey = 'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBA3UAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC35eMaYoJXEoJt5HxarHkzDBEMU3qIWE0HSQ77CwP/8UbX07W2XKwngUyY4k6Hl2M/n9TOZMZsiBzer/fqV+QNPN1m9M94eUm2gQgwkoRj5battRCaNJK/23GGpCsTQatJN8PZBhJBb2Vlsvw5lFrSdMT1R7vaz+2EeNR/FitFXwIDAQAB'
msg = "test"
keyDER = b64decode(pubkey)
keyPub = RSA.importKey(keyDER)
cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(keyPub)
cipher_text = cipher.encrypt(msg.encode())
emsg = b64encode(cipher_text)
print emsg
```

Comment: A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. Please add some description to make others understand. :)

Comment: I am getting in `keyPub = RSA.importKey(keyDER)` -> `RSA.py:588` -> `ValueError: RSA key format is not supported`

Comment: I replaced the single quote with double quotes it worked fine :) for the variable **pubkey**

Comment: @DimaLituiev did you figured out how to solve this?

Comment: If you're getting the "RSA key format not supported", you might have to skip the part where it does the b64decode.

Answer (score 18):

I too had trouble with this. I got it working like this:

```
key = RSA.generate(2048)

binPrivKey = key.exportKey('DER')
binPubKey =  key.publickey().exportKey('DER')

privKeyObj = RSA.importKey(binPrivKey)
pubKeyObj =  RSA.importKey(binPubKey)

msg = "attack at dawn"
emsg = pubKeyObj.encrypt(msg, 'x')[0]
dmsg = privKeyObj.decrypt(emsg)

assert(msg == dmsg)
```

If you're writing to files, you may find it easier to deal with hex strings instead of binary strings. I'm using these helper functions a lot

```
def bin2hex(binStr):
    return binascii.hexlify(binStr)

def hex2bin(hexStr):
    return binascii.unhexlify(hexStr)
```

Comment: This issues an error:
`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py in encrypt(self, plaintext, K) --> 372
NotImplementedError: Use module Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP instead`

Comment: You may have to encode the msg like this `msg.encode("utf-8")`

Comment: pubKeyObj.encrypt  - this is not visible in python 3.8

Answer (score 10):

By using:

```
RSA.importKey(externKey)
```

with parameter externKey look like the following:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAybVqRvfYvWbLsB98BqkD
lWd0/5y6SyhHt6/r6M0l7JXBweqMvxVt7XmI2yqPL56YxzcgQ8ycDkoqHJ+XozgP
iRnLNpYRlCzsiaOElbmQcnrI8iOb9Ahm6j0cbBB1S8VNvD+u9RQJt53zPxPj8/Dq
f1oNGFXOM8udNYWZaRCukLs/TumsAn0a+BF4639WtFiUvTWdVhlyvCQTs49ytRkH
rXH30RkB528RIvTGeW8xBTV4NaiTIzAEKCVSPagLr4Hzbb9b5+bODic/zkLGQazy
/NKOFgiB7kD2+WEMcuhTr5noeXau0PDAhgmrBhzzWOjUwwaO+ACvJLkPXZfjhy7P
+wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

You shouldn't b64decode the externKey and the string should start with "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" and "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----".

Comment: Works for me after adding `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`  and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` and should read `key` from file, `str` is not working

Answer (score 6):

The method I ended up using based on a few answers here:

```py
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5

def encrypt_data(data):
    with open("/path/to/public.pem", "rb") as k:
        key = RSA.importKey(k.read())

    cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
    return cipher.encrypt(data.encode())


def decrypt_data(data):
    with open("path/to/private.pem", "rb") as k:
        key = RSA.importKey(k.read())

    decipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
    return decipher.decrypt(data, None).decode()


message = "hello world!"
encrypted = encrypt_data(message)
decrypted = decrypt_data(message)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html)

```
importKey(externKey, passphrase=None)
Import an RSA key (public or private half), encoded in standard form.
```

Comment: This was the first method that I tried, it would raise "ValueError: RSA key format is not supported".  Then I tried the method (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569189/how-to-read-a-rsa-public-key-in-pem-pkcs1-format-in-python) in my question, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

thanks @user9527 vote up for you

that solved my problem

my env: win10x64 python3.6.4 pycrypto2.6.1

here's my code, encrypt end decrypt, the key was from someone's blog.(if U occured with "ValueError: RSA key format is not supported", check the key format, it should be warpped with some thing like "-----BEGIN XXXX KEY-----")

```
pubkey = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""

prvkey = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"""

from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5

msg = "test"
print("raw msg->", msg)
keyPub = RSA.importKey(pubkey) # import the public key
cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(keyPub)
#print(cipher.encrypt.__doc__)
cipher_text = cipher.encrypt(msg.encode()) # now we have the cipher
print("cipher text->", cipher_text)


keyPriv = RSA.importKey(prvkey) # import the private key
cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(keyPriv)
#print(cipher.decrypt.__doc__)
decrypt_text = cipher.decrypt(cipher_text, None).decode()
print("decrypted msg->", decrypt_text)
assert msg == decrypt_text # check that
print("test passed")
```

the output:

```
raw msg-> test
cipher text-> b'\xb0]\x1f@B\x8b\xb5\xbf\x891:\t4D\x80$\xc0y\xaa\xb4\x86t/|\xeaM%\xf06\x14,\x9e?\x86R\x83\xd72\xe5\xfdsr:\x99\xe7v\xd9]&\xbc\x85\xd3\x16\x80\x19q\xe7\xb1\x89\xff/\x12\xe5\xb3\x9cu\x1f\x04x\xa5\xdfl\xcd\xae_\xba\x1b\x97\x9fa\xcf9O\xbfB\xf6\xd1N\xf5|<\xbf^\x84R\xecSo\x9a*\xf7\x8d\x8e\xbe0Q\xcd\x14\x13\xf98x\xe7\xd8x\x19\xaf\x98\xefu\xa8\xb1\xd3\xfa\xf2N\xca\xb5'
decrypted msg-> test
test passed
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to import an external key using `RSA.importkey( )`, you have two options:

1. Read key from file:

   ```
    file = open('external.pem','r')
    external_key = file.read()
    key = RSA.import_key(external_key)
   ```

   and your external key format must be something like this:

   ```
    -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsDcmhF1kqsMw9HAUc231
    IEr3OwVwocSM4JPUGVSTBDcM9tGoflx8UoN4M9EJrdCcVicZEt709L13jhUxo/hX
    jUDqyQ6U+zyOYhoSwQpHKju2bwn6HMC8iq/ZwNqRFiqa23O2L8WSjZq4J/U1wWZ9
    Zh7f0E5w8GZDkngceQI8nBWFPSAeQNAh0b4Vy1SYKapPrvUJdS9LsT3V9B2k2Nm1
    4lUOtfufpWP5xjoC3MwOxgBsPJsuqpe7sZddG4YzQi3IuMAcc+C/ms9mA7OX5yxt
    xgU3tAIzzBHgvwn9vANNJPzJMaOcm9kKMVJYXLHfg37IfIk1oV+/3BxMQ26ErNcC
    9wIDAQAB
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
   ```

   In Linux (I don't know about Windows) you can check it by this command:

   ```
    less exteralkey.pem
   ```
2. If you wanna hardcode your key into your code, your key must be like this:

   ```
    pubkey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n\
    MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsDcmhF1kqsMw9HAUc231\n\
    IEr3OwVwocSM4JPUGVSTBDcM9tGoflx8UoN4M9EJrdCcVicZEt709L13jhUxo/hX\n\
    jUDqyQ6U+zyOYhoSwQpHKju2bwn6HMC8iq/ZwNqRFiqa23O2L8WSjZq4J/U1wWZ9\n\
    Zh7f0E5w8GZDkngceQI8nBWFPSAeQNAh0b4Vy1SYKapPrvUJdS9LsT3V9B2k2Nm1\n\
    4lUOtfufpWP5xjoC3MwOxgBsPJsuqpe7sZddG4YzQi3IuMAcc+C/ms9mA7OX5yxt\n\
    xgU3tAIzzBHgvwn9vANNJPzJMaOcm9kKMVJYXLHfg37IfIk1oV+/3BxMQ26ErNcC\n\
    9wIDAQAB\n\
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
   ```

   then you can import it:

   ```
    key = RSA.importkey(pubkey)
   ```

**Note**: if you do not add `"\n"` to the end of each line of your RSA key the `RSA.importkey( )` will raise an error:

> RSA key format is not supported

**Note 2**: I used `"\"` to indicate that statement is continued on the next line.

Comment: Please, avoid using "SMS language" (u, ur idk) in Stoack Overflow answers. The require a minimum quality level. I've edited it.

Comment: it works!! Thanks and the method name should be import_key :)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.
Python 3.8

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo pip3 list|grep crypto

cryptography           2.8

cryptography-vectors   2.8

pycrypto               2.6.1

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5

def encrypt_data(data):
    with open("/home/echague/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", "rb") as k:
        key_pub = RSA.importKey(k.read())

    cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(key_pub)
    return cipher.encrypt(data.encode())


def decrypt_data(data):
    with open("/home/echague/.ssh/id_rsa", "rb") as k:
        key_priv = RSA.importKey(k.read())

    decipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(key_priv)
    return decipher.decrypt(data, None).decode()


message = "hello world!"
encrypted = encrypt_data(message)
decrypted = decrypt_data(encrypted)
print(message)
print(encrypted)
print(decrypted)
```

Comment: Would you please be able to improve your answer by adding some comments to it explaining what it does?