# Encrypting json with pem file in python giving RSA key format is not supported

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa, pycrypto

I am working on a encryption module in which the request takes parameters in encrypted JSON form. This encryption is done by a public key provided from the server as follows,

```
def encrypt_bank_request(request_payload):
    key = ""
    url = "http://localhost/payment/gateways/mybank.pem"
    file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    decoded_file = file.read().decode("utf-8")
    for line in decoded_file:
        key += line

    keyDER = base64.b64decode(key)
    keyPub = RSA.importKey(keyDER)
    cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(keyPub)
    cipher_text = cipher.encrypt(request_payload.encode())
    emsg = base64.b64encode(cipher_text)
    print(emsg);
```

but when I am executing the code, I am getting following at `keyPub = RSA.importKey(keyDER)`,

> ValueError at /
>
> RSA key format is not supported

The PHP equivalent of what I am trying to achieve is as follows,

```
$pemKey = file_get_contents("http://localhost/payment/gateways/mybank.pem");
openssl_public_encrypt($request_payload, $encrypted, $pemKey);
```

`openssl_public_encrypt` as the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) suggests encrypts data with public key and stores the result into `$encrypted`.

What am I doing wrong here? is it because the function expects RSA key object and I am providing string, in that case how do I convert string to RSA key object.

I have referred the following,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46356449/11782743

Thank you for your suggestions.

P.S. my key is as following,

```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```

Comment: the key string. that you show  is missing the `-----BEGIN...` and `----END` lines

I'd expect something like:
`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` then your string, then `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: Further you key string seems broken.

When I add manually the `BEGIN` and `END` lines and I try to use `openssl` to parse the string with the command
`openssl rsa -in keyfile.key -noout -text` , then I get an output like `unable to load Private Key
139695176668824:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1217:
`

if I load one of my valid key files I get complete information about the key looking a little like `Private-Key: (2048 bit)
modulus:
    00:af:9e:d8:fa:9d:7e:da:21:e1:ce:5d:39:eb:aa:`

Comment: the key originally had `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` but whenever I executed I get `Incorrect padding`

Comment: and when i check online on https://8gwifi.org/PemParserFunctions.jsp it gives me correct info about the key.

Comment: What you have is not a public key, it is an X.509 certificate. Inside that certificate, in just one of the fields, is the public key. You either need to put the `BEGIN..` and `END ...` lines back in, or base64 decode what you have and supply that to import_key. I assume you're using the pycryptodome package, right?

Comment: Just wanted to say, that the length seems a little excessive for a public key and whether you really receive a public key?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk beat me to it.

Comment: The lines `for line in decoded_file:  key += line` seem to do nothing useful. you just take the string read from file and recompose it character by character.
It should be identical to just writing: `key = file.read().decode("utf-8")`

But if this is a cert, then don't confuse yourself with wrong names and call it `cert_str` or something like that. It will also help to understand the code lateron

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk how do i get the public key from that certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [PyCryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), not PyCrypto, and the key must either be base-64 with proper `-----BEGIN...` and `-----END...` lines, or you must base64-decode your base64-encoded blob yourself and supply the resulting bytes to [`RSA.import_key()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html?highlight=certificate#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.import_key)

```py
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA

cert = '''MIIGPjCCBSagAwIBAgIRAJig5hCghJQ8AAAAAFDbeaEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgboxCzAJBgNV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'''

cert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + cert + '\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----'


r = RSA.importKey(cert)
print(r.n)
```

prints out the modulus

```
835530417319735322904421462459451063654010910036490131542528939590706305612565738190465258970018362442504314027037982757378964476628610126628643741295376455983157717853926501344173174543509081666215334337886432121330318119586463591986644236407155160633403615394726359135900210267964618093240043978235544727335109686553571844741498488578037894004729516832328328853475766210938149668579224549929585498616511012055116486617256405348752281221841113593203898211327673790225447988279497436707544397419647915422702720143667984437532004226144606948907602116888194895153345334011560415740885466004583157439110458828130795408434017885187061379936745660293815100292079970030432352403962499538301054633885062147509036462581226410523337358445683232465510709519096907784307249725979290562163532705329623550196710312110800265447584580251840590731044582860060553698109052225806921430613417139832332963970234067131600542381764969722189768692969004592637189607748143035304212536331626692025074578149324603263114533612082445070491074737755256358022645183110670751682994979892626789172684974128522083229506601674218910572247739238520579221342029941195041299137018203411248036919473974612176366220589057599358170063558334757947393372489019738067582542051
```