# How to load a RSA public key using Python's cryptography module

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm trying to load a public key using the [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/) module, this is what the key looks like:

```
>>> print(pubkey)
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC+6gvHdCUCjnc4hSMwbdIIspk4
69pVAzjjb8tDJsCH/QpiK9vXe4nDZ7p9kiw2ACw0fkWaPnApKBwXNB9Nd9Sf+XFt
cIzdqKKBcAqZZCu2pA729amNRug9DoZdkstaBG+VfTxXhdzQRSTxxqJQWgdV8ejK
kt4D1M6pAiTkAyD0eQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I'm trying to load it using the [`load_pem_public_key()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.load_pem_public_key) method:

```
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_public_key
>>> load_pem_public_key(pubkey, default_backend())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/elias/.virtualenvs/ckpypkg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py", line 24, in load_pem_public_key
    return backend.load_pem_public_key(data)
  File "/home/elias/.virtualenvs/ckpypkg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py", line 285, in load_pem_public_key
    return b.load_pem_public_key(data)
  File "/home/elias/.virtualenvs/ckpypkg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1376, in load_pem_public_key
    self._handle_key_loading_error()
  File "/home/elias/.virtualenvs/ckpypkg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1595, in _handle_key_loading_error
    raise ValueError("Could not unserialize key data.")
ValueError: Could not unserialize key data.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there something wrong with this key? Why can't it be unserialized?

OpenSSL version:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

**UPDATE:** I just tested the same code with a different key (the same one from [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569189/how-to-read-a-rsa-public-key-in-pem-pkcs1-format)) and it worked, which makes this yet more puzzling: why it works for that key and not for mine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Long story short, apparently your PEM has the header and footer of PKCS#1 format(`-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`) but contains the DER sequence for PKCS#8 format, because of that `load_pem_public_key` cannot unserialize the pem properly, because it expects an PKCS#1 DER format, but receives an PKCS#8 format. Quick fix by replacing header and footer with those corresponding to PKCS#8 format.

In your pem file replace `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` with `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`, and `-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` with `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

Your public key should look like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC+6gvHdCUCjnc4hSMwbdIIspk4
69pVAzjjb8tDJsCH/QpiK9vXe4nDZ7p9kiw2ACw0fkWaPnApKBwXNB9Nd9Sf+XFt
cIzdqKKBcAqZZCu2pA729amNRug9DoZdkstaBG+VfTxXhdzQRSTxxqJQWgdV8ejK
kt4D1M6pAiTkAyD0eQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

otherwise the [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) module will not be able to parse it.

---

**EDIT**

`-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` is for PKCS#1, and `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` is for PKCS#8

You can check out your DER format by doing the following:

```
from Crypto.Util.asn1 import DerSequence
public_key_der = DerSequence()
public_key_der.decode('MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC+6gvHdCUCjnc4hSMwbdIIspk469pVAzjjb8tDJsCH/QpiK9vXe4nDZ7p9kiw2ACw0fkWaPnApKBwXNB9Nd9Sf+XFtcIzdqKKBcAqZZCu2pA729amNRug9DoZdkstaBG+VfTxXhdzQRSTxxqJQWgdV8ejKkt4D1M6pAiTkAyD0eQIDAQAB'.decode('base64'));
for k,v in enumerate(public_key_der):
    print k, v
```

you will notice that your `public_key_der[0]` is another DER Sequence(you can actually decode it again: `public_key_der.decode(public_key_der[0])`), and represents the AlgorithmIdentifier sequence from PKCS#8 DER format, if it were PKCS#1 `public_key_der[0]` should have an INTEGER which represents the modulus.

more info about PKCS#8 vs PKCS#1 formats can be found here: https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem

Comment: uh, are you sure? because that would be so weird! can you point to any source confirming that behavior?

Comment: This can't be the reason, I just tested with another key (from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569189/how-to-read-a-rsa-public-key-in-pem-pkcs1-format) and it worked.

Comment: -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- is for PKCS#1 standard, and -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- is for PKCS#8 standard. I decoded your public key and it's der sequence fits that of PKCS#8. You can find more info about how DER sequence differs from PKCS#1 vs PKCS#8 here: https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem. Btw, I did test my answer before posting it, and it worked. You should've at least try it before giving up.

Comment: Thanks for that reference -- yeah, I had tried it and noticed that it didn't fail, but was not sure it had actually done the right thing, so I was hoping for an explanation which you've now given, so thank you. :)

Comment: Great, it's much clear now, upvoted! Yeah, I suppose I should tell Travis-CI folks, I'm getting the PEM from their API with: `curl https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/scrapinghub/skinfer/key`

Answer (score 18):

You are trying to treat the key like a PEM encoded RSA key, but in fact what you have is public key using PKCS#1 format.  The data between `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` is actually just base-64 encoded DER data.  There may be a library function to get at this (I started looking through the `cryptography` documentation and my eyes started to glaze over), but the following will work...

We start with your key data:

```
>>> print pubkey
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC+6gvHdCUCjnc4hSMwbdIIspk4
69pVAzjjb8tDJsCH/QpiK9vXe4nDZ7p9kiw2ACw0fkWaPnApKBwXNB9Nd9Sf+XFt
cIzdqKKBcAqZZCu2pA729amNRug9DoZdkstaBG+VfTxXhdzQRSTxxqJQWgdV8ejK
kt4D1M6pAiTkAyD0eQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

We drop the `BEGIN` and `END` lines:

```
>>> b64data = '\n'.join(pubkey.splitlines()[1:-1])
>>> print b64data
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC+6gvHdCUCjnc4hSMwbdIIspk4
69pVAzjjb8tDJsCH/QpiK9vXe4nDZ7p9kiw2ACw0fkWaPnApKBwXNB9Nd9Sf+XFt
cIzdqKKBcAqZZCu2pA729amNRug9DoZdkstaBG+VfTxXhdzQRSTxxqJQWgdV8ejK
kt4D1M6pAiTkAyD0eQIDAQAB
```

And then we base64 decode the data:

```
>>> derdata = base64.b64decode(b64data)
```

Now we have the DER encoded public key, so we can feed this to
`load_der_public_key`:

```
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_der_public_key
>>> key = load_der_public_key(derdata, default_backend())
>>> print key
<cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.rsa._RSAPublicKey object at 0x7fe590ea6d10>
```

Comment: And in this answer, we're doing pretty much the same thing as in the first answer in the [question to which you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569189/how-to-read-a-rsa-public-key-in-pem-pkcs1-format)...